# Very new at Android development; how do I add a Java lib to Android Studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio, java

I faked my way into the screen below with some ease in Android Studio. I had no intention of trying to make the app DO anything; just a first step toward an actual working model (which I have for Windows). Took several hours--one reason: managed to screw up first attempt so that I couldn't make gradle happy [much time spent here] and had/chose to start over. I don't want to do that again, so I'm being cautious since I'm on shaky newbie ground.

[image]

I added the non-GUI part of my working Netbeans app with no problem.

I copied the method below from my working project in Netbeans. I know that I don't need this module to compile, since the Android GUI mechanism is so different:

```
private static void onClickShow(ActionEvent e) {

    int rowsShown;
    ArrayList<String> comb = null;
...
}
```

**But suppose I did need to import that class** from `java.awt.event`.

**Sooner or later I'm going to have to include a java library for some reason. Yes?** (If not, I guess I've asked a bad question!)

Just to see if I could import, I got myself to the screen below by clicking `File | Project Structure` and adding `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar` (which is where Netbeans told me I'd find java.awt.event).

[image]

I thought I'd better hold off doing anything else until I get this question answered:

**IS the highlighted bottom line above HOW TO ADD A JAVA LIBRARY to an Android Studio project?**

(I've Googled and read but little applies to Android Studio, so I'm at my own mercy at interpreting and I need other eyes to help ensure I don't screw up this project since gradle is involved again.)

Comment: Are you asking about how to write your own library project or how to include a 3rd party library into your app? These are two very different things.

Comment: You cannot just use a Java library, some are compatible, but not all. The reason for this is that while you use mostly Java to write an Android app, it is technically not really Java, it's just very Java-like. Most java libraries that support Android have a separate version of the  library for Android.

Comment: So I guess what I'm saying is that you cannot just use awt on Android. It's not part of the framework so it doesn't exist there. Android  has its own GUI technology.

Comment: @X--I upvoted the wrong comment, but they're both yours, so it works out. Won't I sometime have to use something is SOME Java lib that isn't already inside Android Studio? Or is that just plain ignorant since they've loaded all that anyone would/could ever use? I'm so new at Android Studio that, before I asked my question, I didn't realize that `External Libraries` contains `rt.jar` and a whole lot more.

Comment: @Code---good point; BOTH!?! Anyway, I was asking how to include a 3rd party library, and now that I've "found" the `External Libraries` tab, I'm wondering if THERE is where I'd add a 3rd party lib instead of where I DID almost add it. I'm pretty sure I would have added it in the wrong place, so I guess the answer to my question is NO.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put dependencies in your build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
compile "your jar location"
```

}

Comment: @uuser--Like so, for example? `dependencies { compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) }`? I assume the `include` argument is optional...(?)

Comment: In Android 1.0.2, you don't need to change `build.gradle`. It's already set up to include all jar files in `libs`. Just copy the jar file there and you're set.

Note: if you're a new Android Studio user, you might be surprised that copying a jar into libs doesn't seem to cause any change. That's because the default Project Structure view "helps" you by not showing you some files and directories. To see the actual jar, select the spinner just above Project Structure and change it from Android to Project.